# How to display the length of string in textfield using events in angular.?

Tags: angular, events, angular-ng-if

I am doing a task where i need to display the length of the string entered into the textfield using Events. One more additional condition is if the string length is greater than 4 then only it will display the length which should be achieved by using ngIf.

Work Done by me till now
In HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Default Message" 
    [(ngModel)]="tname"
    (tname)="event('tname')">
    {{s}}
</div>
```

**In .ts**

```
tname:string;
k:number;
event(s:string){
this.k = s.length ;
 console.log(s);
}
```

Comment: you can also achieve the same without an event  and ngIf   `{{ (tname && tname.length > 4)  ? tname.length : '' }}`

Comment: i need to use this,its mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already bind `tname` using `ngModel` directive which is two-way binding. So just `tname`.length will solve your problem.

**Here is solution**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Default Message" 
    [(ngModel)]="tname"
    (tname)="event('tname')">
    {{s}}
 <span *ngIf="this.k > 4"> Length is {{this.k}}></span>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
event(s:string){
  this.k = this.tname.length ;
    console.log(this.k); // displaying  length
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: please check updated answer. what error you getting?

Comment: it isn't showing any error.It is just not showing the length.

Comment: this do wotrk the condition is i need to add a submit button which calls the event function.

Comment: what if i need to add a background color say Red color if the length is less than 4??

Comment: use ngClass or ngStyle to apply a style based on condition. here is link  https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw1f8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html @TheParam see i have done almost every thing now just need to follow the conditiom that bg-color red if less than 4

Answer (score 4):

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" /> <strong>Result- {{value}}</strong>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

TS file

```
  value;
  onKeyUp(e) {
    this.value = e.target.value.length;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are expecting 
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylxrwp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: it did worked,! but can it be done without using changeEvent and  ngModelchange.beacuse these topics haven't yet covered in my course.

Comment: change in a model can be easily detected by a ngModelChange and change events.

Comment: ya but that topic is still pending for me to learn..sp just need the basic method to display the length by using ngIf and events

Comment: what if i need to add an background color if the length of string is less than 4??

Comment: i want the textfield-where we are entering the string- to change the color if length is less than 4

Comment: I have updated example if u found the answer satisfactory please mark my answer as accepted. :)

Comment: it is working but again i need to do it without using ngStyle or ngClass..https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw1f8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.htmlthis is what i have done have a look and try if you can help me with this..

Comment: like we can use it using true and false condition

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer which i got..
in HTML

```
<div class="container">Name:<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Default Message" 
[(ngModel)]="tname"
(change)="event('change')"><br>
<span *ngIf="this.k >=4"> Length={{k}}</span>
</div>
```

IN .ts

```
 tname:string='';
 k:number=0;
 event(s:string){
 this.k = this.tname.length ;
 console.log(this.k);
}
```